# Do deleted Amazon S3 Bucket names become available for re-use

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

If I delete a Bucket from my Amazon S3 account, does the name become available for use elsewhere?
I setup a bucket named "WXY234" in my S3 account, but now I'd like to have that bucket name in a different account. If I delete it from my account, will the name be released into the wild so I can use it elsewhere? If so, how long does it take for the released name to become available?

Comment: It usually only takes a few minutes for the name to become available again.

Comment: My experience says that it can take around 1 hour to be available again after delete

Comment: There are threads that lead to believe it can take up to several hours as it is "eventually consistent". As of December 2019:https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-conflicting-conditional-operation/

Answer (score 17):

From Amazon S3 documentation [Bucket Restrictions and Limitations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html):

> Bucket ownership is not transferable; however, if a bucket is empty, you can delete it. After a bucket is deleted, **the name becomes available to reuse, but the name might not be available for you to reuse for various reasons**. For example, some other account could create a bucket with that name. Note, too, that it might take some time before the name can be reused. So if you want to use the same bucket name, don't delete the bucket.

Comment: This entire answer was taken from the official documentation; a link was provided, but the fact that it was a copy/paste was not clearly indicated.  Formatted as a block quote to clarify this.

Comment: As mentioned by another user in previous comment, I was able to reuse the bucket name after few minutes of deleting the existing bucket.

Answer (score 8):

It takes about an hour if you are switching the region with same bucket name.

Comment: Echo that. It took exactly an hour to switch regions.

Answer (score 0):

It took me around 2 hours, for creating the same bucket in a different account and in a different region.
But if we want to create in the same account and same region, it will get created at the same time instantly, since it keeps a backup for that account for some time.